# Electrical Power sensor

Tags: sensor, electromagnetic

1.I need a sensor for measuring the electrical power without cutting the isolation of a wire. Is there a such sensor?

2.Is it possible to use the magnetic field of a wire(220v) to power a very small circuit? Where I can find such a device?

Thank you!

Comment: Would a Split Core CT be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Current transformer is evidently what you're looking for. If you can disconnect and reconnect the wire to thread it through the transformer, it's easier/cheaper - if you need to attach without disconnecting the wire, you need a split core type as @Tyler notes.

There's a tradeoff (to the point of a dichotomy, IMHO) between making an accurate measurement and trying to power something from a current transformer. Likewise, if there's no current being drawn, there's no power for your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Power is volts x amps so, without knowing the voltage on the line you cannot accurately determine power. You could assume the voltage is "normal" for your area and measure current through a CT but, you won't know the phase relationship between volts and amps so you cannot possibly know how to modify the V.A result with power factor (basically PF is the cosine of the phase angle between voltage and current).

You could (if you were skilled enough), seperate live and neutral wires and capacitively connect both wires individually to an instrumentation amplifier to determine the line voltage. This, of course, is tricky and given that you are asking such a basic question there is no point going into the details at the risk of encouraging you to mess around with live wires.

> Is it possible to use the magnetic field of a wire(220v) to power a
>   very small circuit?

Yes this is possible and using a CT is a good way however, if there is no current in the way (appliances switched off) then there is no magnetic field and no signal from the CT's output.